# generar un reporte en excel pero con caracteres especiales "como Ñ"

Tags: php, mysql, web, desarrollo

He podido hacer mi conexcion a base de datos correcta y que aparescan mis datos en una celdas con html y css, tambien pude generado un excel pero al abrirlo los caracteres especiales como las ´,Ñ,etc.. no me los lee excel y me remplaza esos caracteres por Ã o ©. e intentado ponerle un charset=iso-8859-1 y aun con esas me sigue apareciendo, estos es parte de mi codigo

introducir el código aquí
//esto es una pagina que contiene este codigo que es el que me visualiza la tabla y el boton para mandar hacer mi excel

````
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>nombre</td>
                <td>ap_paterno</td>
                <td>ap_materno</td>
                <td>titulo</td>
                <td>especialidad</td>
                <td>cedula</td>
                <td>sexo</td>
                <td>calle</td>
                <td>colonia</td>
                <td>cp</td>
                <td>ciudad</td>
                <td>estado</td>
                <td>pais</td>
                <td>telefono</td>
                <td>fijo</td>
            </tr>
            <!--lista pero con php-->
            <?php
            include ("../abrir_conexion.php");
                $sql="SELECT * FROM especialistas";
                $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {
                

            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $fila[0] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[1] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[2] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[3] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[4] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[5] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[6] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[7] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[8] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[9] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[10] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[11] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[12] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[13] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[14] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila[15] ?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php } ?>
<a href="./excel.php" class="btn-small blue z-depth-2">descargar excel</a>```
````

//este es un documento aparte que se enlaza con el boton para generar el excel.

````
<?php 
header("content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel ");
header("content-Disposition: attachment; filename=tbespecialistas.xls");
header("pragma: no-cache");
header("expires: 0");




?>

<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>id</td>
                    <td>nombre</td>
                    <td>ap_paterno</td>
                    <td>ap_materno</td>
                    <td>titulo</td>
                    <td>especialidad</td>
                    <td>cedula</td>
                    <td>sexo</td>
                    <td>calle</td>
                    <td>colonia</td>
                    <td>cp</td>
                    <td>ciudad</td>
                    <td>estado</td>
                    <td>pais</td>
                    <td>telefono</td>
                    <td>fijo</td>
                </tr>
                <!--lista pero con php-->
                <?php
                include ("../abrir_conexion.php");
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM especialistas";
                    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                    while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {
                    

                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[0] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[1] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[2] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[3] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[4] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[5] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[6] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[7] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[8] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[9] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[10] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[11] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[12] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[13] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[14] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[15] ?></td>
                </tr>

                <?php } ?>

            </table>```
````

Comment: ¿Si muestras el contenido como texto aparece bien? En el tipo de archivo ponle también un charser utf8 y respeta la convención en los header

Comment: Si la respuesta fue útil, considera aceptarla con el check que aparece al lado izquierdo y darle también al upvote. También te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya me ha sucedido anteriormente, prueba de esta forma, debería funcionar

```
<?php 
header("content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel ");
header("content-Disposition: attachment; filename=tbespecialistas.xls");
header("pragma: no-cache");
header("expires: 0");
?>

<!--ACENTOS Y CARACTERES RAROS OFF-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>id</td>
                    <td>nombre</td>
                    <td>ap_paterno</td>
                    <td>ap_materno</td>
                    <td>titulo</td>
                    <td>especialidad</td>
                    <td>cedula</td>
                    <td>sexo</td>
                    <td>calle</td>
                    <td>colonia</td>
                    <td>cp</td>
                    <td>ciudad</td>
                    <td>estado</td>
                    <td>pais</td>
                    <td>telefono</td>
                    <td>fijo</td>
                </tr>
                <!--lista pero con php-->
                <?php
                include ("../abrir_conexion.php");
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM especialistas";
                    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                    while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {
                    

                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[0] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[1] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[2] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[3] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[4] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[5] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[6] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[7] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[8] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[9] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[10] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[11] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[12] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[13] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[14] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fila[15] ?></td>
                </tr>

                <?php } ?>

            </table>
```

**Explicación**: colocar dentro de la cabecera (header) el formato de codificación UTF-8. En caso de no funcionar, podemos retroalimentarlo en los comentarios

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: ya lo tenia. tambien revise si era la base de datos pero no hay errores si me proyecta bien los datos. en el unico lugar donde no me lee los caracteres especiales es en excel.

Comment: encontre el error. gracias bro si me sirvio tu consejo era yo el que estaba mal por el estres no analise bien y si era lo que me faltaba lo que me pusistes.